# Index in position 1 is invalid; previous version of code works

Tags: matlab

Here is the first iteration of my code, which correctly fills the matrix `laseridx` with the entries of matrix Data that correspond to the indices of `pulsestart` and `pulseend`:

```
Camel = numel(pulsestart)-1;
CCamel = cell(1,Camel);
for ni = 1:Camel 
    Ccamel{ni} = pulsestart(ni):pulseend(ni);
end
laseridx = [];
laseridx(:,2) = [Ccamel{:}];

laseridx(:,1) = Data(laseridx(:,2),1);
laseridx(:,3) = Data(laseridx(:,2),3);
```

Here is version two, which is now filling the matrix `snipidx`. The only difference is now instead of `pulsestart` and `pulseend`, the matrix `famousdex` has two columns which correspond to the start and end of the sample I'd like to analyze:

```
for ni = 1:Camel
      Ccamel{ni} = famousdex(ni,1):famousdex(ni,2);
end
snipidx = [];
snipidx(:,2) = [Ccamel{:}]; 

snipidx(:,1) = Data(snipidx(:,2),1); % line with issue
snipidx(:,3) = Data(snipidx(:,2),3);
```

However, when I run the second version I get the following error:

> Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive
>   integers or logical values.
>
> Error in Analyze2 (line 74)
>               snipidx(:,1) = Data(snipidx(:,2),1);

How do I resolve this error?

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15NO8dJWJ_-HBK6qpKODNMSZZhbVKSLIl/view?usp=sharing) to `snipidx(:,2)`.

Comment: somewhere in `snipidx(:,2)` there is a value that is not a positive integer, Without the data its hard to tell. Could you show us some sample data?

Comment: `snipidx(:,2)` is all numbers, it's populated by the earlier Ccamel. I just ran `find(isnan(snipidx(:,2)))` and it returned empty.

I'm not sure how to add sample data. I'll try to poke around the post.

I just tried isinteger and it returned 0, so you're right! I'll look around the data and see what's amiss.

Comment: You’ve described the problem well, such that it is obvious what the problem is (see comment above), but still the question is not answerable because we don’t have your data. Please see [mcve].

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15NO8dJWJ_-HBK6qpKODNMSZZhbVKSLIl/view?usp=sharing) here is a google drive link to my data. I used `isinteger(1)` and it returns 0, so if I do `isinteger(snipidx(:,2))` and it also returns 0, does that not mean that there are only integers in `snipidx(:,2)`? I think I was misunderstanding what `isinteger()` does, earlier.

Comment: yes, there is a little misunderstanding. `isinteger()` does not check whether the value of a variable is an integer, but if the variable is of integer data type format. you have to check with `mod()` and `<1` to see if the values fit

Comment: also i just took a quick look at your link. there seems to be something off with the data. the lowest value seems to be somewhere around 800,000 and the highest is around 21 million. you might have to check there, because i doubt that `Data` has so much entries.

Comment: There are so many entries; we use a real-time feedback system that operates around 24kHz, so every 24,000 lines is 1 second.